# Change Facebook comment tool notification URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I have created an app using Facebook Canvas and loaded it as a Page Tab on a Facebook Page. The app is basically a simple site that contains several pages, each with an own comment section (Facebook Comments).

When someone leaves a comment and I reply to it, that person gets a Facebook notification saying "[Name] replied to your comment on [url]". There are two issues with this:
1. The server that we put the app on has an ugly url. We do not want to show the url anywhere. That's why we wanted to use the Facebook Canvas in the first place - so that you could view the app inside Facebook and not on the server itself.
2. When you click the notification, it brings you to the app OUTSIDE of Facebook. It sends to you that ugly url. I wish for it to take you to the app INSIDE Facebook, that is facebook.com/[our_page]/app_[app_id]

I was wondering if there is there any way to 1) change the url that the notification outputs and 2) the url that the notification sends you to.

Hope someone can help with this!

Comment: Comments made using the Comments Plugin are tied to the URL you specify in the `data-href` parameter – if you want those to be “prettier”, then _use_ prettier URLs in that place. (They would have to be URLs under your control though, because you need to set them up to provide appropriate Open Graph meta data to the FB scraper.) And you can redirect users “landing” on such a URL when they click on a comment notification back to your app on Facebook using JavaScript for example. (You can use a server-side redirect too, but then you have to add an exception for the FB scraper.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that setting the data-href to the https://apps.facebook.com/**app-name** solves the problem. When someone uses the comments form and they are replied to, the Facebook notification will say "[Name] replied to your comment of [App name].

The issue that remains is that this does not give you a separate comment tool on each page.